# Avoid edges and labels overlapping automatically

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, graphs, edge

I would like to avoid edges and labels overlapping. I have seen different solutions, but all of them need manual adjustments. However, I need to produce several graph like the one below and find it too time expensive to adjust where the edges should start and end as well as where the labels should be placed manually.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    roundnode/.style={circle, draw=green!60, fill=green!5, very thick, minimum size=7mm}
    ]

    %Nodes
    \node[roundnode](s) at (4,4) {s};
    \node[roundnode](1) at (-2,2) {1};
    \node[roundnode](2) at (2,2) {2};
    \node[roundnode](3) at (6,2) {3};
    \node[roundnode](4) at (10,2) {4};
    \node[roundnode](t) at (4,0) {t};

    %Lines
    \draw[thick, ->] (s) edge [bend right=15] node[pos=0.5, above]{8-$\phi$} (1);
    \draw[thick, ->] (1) edge [bend right=15] node[pos=0.5, above]{$\phi$} (s);
    \draw[thick, ->] (s) -- (3) node[pos=0.5, above]{8};
    \draw[thick, ->] (s) -- (4) node[pos=0.5, above]{8};
    \draw[thick, ->] (2) -- (1) node[pos=0.5, above]{$\phi$};
    \draw[thick, ->] (2) edge [bend right=15] node[pos=0.5, above]{$1-\phi$} (3);
    \draw[thick, ->] (3) edge [bend right=15] node[pos=0.5, above]{$\phi$} (2);
    \draw[thick, ->] (3) edge [bend right=15] node[pos=0.5, above]{$1-\phi$} (4);
    \draw[thick, ->] (4) edge [bend right=15] node[pos=0.5, above]{$\phi$} (3);
    \draw[thick, ->] (1) -- (t) node[pos=0.5, above]{8};
    \draw[thick, ->] (2) -- (t) node[pos=0.5, above]{8};
    \draw[thick, ->] (4) edge [bend right=15] node[pos=0.5, above]{$8-\phi$} (t);
    \draw[thick, ->] (t) edge [bend right=15] node[pos=0.5, above]{$\phi$} (4);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Flow increased through path $P_1$}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the graphdrawing library of tikz? It features some default layouts.